# Prove that if $v\in T_p(M)$ and $f=0$ in a neighborhood of $p$, then $v(f)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying Semi-Riemannian Geometry by Newman and reading the following Theorem:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, with $p\in M$ and $v\in T_p(M)$. If $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $f=0$ in a neighborhood of $p$, then $v(f)=0$.

The proof given in the book uses bump functions, but I was wondering: what's wrong with the following simpler approach?

Suppose $f$ is  zero in the neighborhood $U$ of $p$. Thus in $U$, $cf=0$ for all real $c$. Now $v(cf)=cv(f)$ for any real $c$. So $v(0)=cv(0)$ which is possible only if $v(f)=v(0)=0$.

My intuition says that this small proof is wrong or incomplete, but I can't figure out why. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're implicitly assuming the thing you're trying to prove.

Indeed $v(cf) = cv(f)$ for all $c$, and indeed (writing $0_M$ for the zero *function* on $M$, for clarity), you are correct to say it follows from this that $v(0_M) = 0$. However, I don't see how you can conclude that $v(f) = v(0_M)$.

(The result you're trying to prove would imply that if two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal on $U$, then $v(f) = v(g)$ (prove it as an exercise!), but you don't know that until you establish this fact.)

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess what I _can_ conclude is that the restriction of $f$ to $U$, or $f_U$ equals $0_U$? From this, I can say that both $f_U$ and $0_U$ have the same domain and equal everywhere in that domain, so both of them are one and the same. So $v(f_U)=v(0_U)=0$. But I think this chain of reasoning would only hold if $v\in T_p(U)$ rather than $v\in T_p(M)$, where I'm treating $U$ itself as a smooth manifold with subspace topology?

Comment: Yes, this line of reasoning only makes sense once you can show that there's a reasonable injection $T_p(M) \to T_p(U)$. On a meta level, at some point you really do have to use the Leibniz rule for $v$ (that is, $v(fg) = v(f)g(p) + f(p)v(g)$)-- that's exactly the condition that forces $v$ to be a "local" object.